# MPAndroidGraph 'no suitable constructor found for BarEntry(float,float[]) '

Tags: android, constructor

I get the following error when trying to compile a stacked bargraph. I have copied code working for a grouped bargraph and am trying to add the "stacked" functionality to this code. The error is marked in comments in the code below, in each of the bar entry lines as per following example:
"
BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(0f, new float[]{10,20,20});
"
Here is the code:

```
public class StackedBarGraph extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.groupedbargraph);

        BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.mpandroidstackedbargraph );
        BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(),getDataSet());       //!! ignore the complaint - it compiles and works
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.setDescription("My Chart");
        chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
        chart.invalidate();
    }

    private ArrayList<IBarDataSet> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = null;
        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(0f, new float[]{10,20,20}); // ERROR
        valueSet1.add(v1e1);  //THESE LINES ALL GIVE ABOVE ERROR
        BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(1f, new float[]{20,30,30}); // ERROR
        valueSet1.add(v1e2);
        BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(2f, new float[]{30,50,40}); // ERROR
        valueSet1.add(v1e3);
        BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(3f, new float[]{50,70,50}); // ERROR
        valueSet1.add(v1e4);
        BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(4f, new float[]{70,40,60}); // ERROR
        valueSet1.add(v1e5);
        BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(5f, new float[]{40,30,70}); // Jun
        valueSet1.add(v1e6);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet2 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v2e1 = new BarEntry(0, new float[]{10,20,30}); // ERROR
        valueSet2.add(v2e1);
        BarEntry v2e2 = new BarEntry(1, new float[]{10,20,30}); // ERROR
        valueSet2.add(v2e2);
        BarEntry v2e3 = new BarEntry(2, new float[]{10,20,30}); // ERROR
        valueSet2.add(v2e3);
        BarEntry v2e4 = new BarEntry(3, new float[]{10,20,30}); // ERROR
        valueSet2.add(v2e4);
        BarEntry v2e5 = new BarEntry(4, new float[]{10,20,30}); // ERROR
        valueSet2.add(v2e5);
        BarEntry v2e6 = new BarEntry(5, new float[]{10,20,30}); // ERROR
        valueSet2.add(v2e6);

        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Brand 1");
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));     // Green
        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 155));   // Light Blue

        dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
        return dataSets;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
        ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
        xAxis.add("JAN");
        xAxis.add("FEB");
        xAxis.add("MAR");
        xAxis.add("APR");
        xAxis.add("MAY");
        xAxis.add("JUN");
        return xAxis;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

BarEntry contains the following constructors:

`BarEntry(float[] vals, int xIndex)`

`BarEntry(float val, int xIndex)`

`BarEntry(float[] vals, int xIndex, String label)`

`BarEntry(float val, int xIndex, Object data)`

So, what your doing is not possible. Flip your arguments...

i.e

```
BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(new float[]{10,20,20}, 0);
```

Please look into the source code for details.